# Is there any other sparse matrix data in matlab built-in file?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, linear-system

I want to do some numerical examples solving large sparse linear system `Ax=b`. And I want to use some  data from Maltab itself because this experiments are easily reproduced any time using Matlab. For example,

```matlab
load west0479.mat
A = west0479;
b = sum(A,2);
gmres(A,b);
bicgstab(A,b);
```

Using these codes, I can obtain a sparse matrix linear system.
I want to ask whether there are some other sparse matrix data in Matlab? If so, please give me some examples.

Comment: do you mean other .mat files with sparse matrices that come right away with every distribution of Matlab?

Comment: yes, any else **.mat** file representing matlab sparse matrix? Like west0479.mat above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many sparse matrices in [Matrix Market](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/)

> A visual repository of test data for use in comparative studies of
>   algorithms for numerical linear algebra, featuring nearly 500 sparse
>   matrices from a variety of applications, as well as matrix generation
>   tools and services.

Use Matrix Market in conjunction with [MM_TO_MSM: Matrix Market File to MATLAB Sparse Matrix](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/mm_to_msm/mm_to_msm.html).

> MM_TO_MSM, a MATLAB library which reads the information stored in a
>   Matrix Market file, and sets it up as a MATLAB sparse matrix.

Matrix Market includes [Matlab Procedures for Reading/Writing Harwell-Boeing Files](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#hb-code-m)

> The Berkeley Benchmarking and Optimization (BeBOP) Group has developed
>   a library and standalone utility for converting between
>   Harwell-Boeing, Matrix Market, and MATLAB sparse matrix formats.

which will allow you to import the Harwell-Boeing collection of matrices from https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/

Comment: Thanks very much. Except the matrix market, any else **.mat** file representing matlab sparse matrix which is built-in matlab software? Like **west0479.mat** above. Thanks.

Comment: @Federico Poloni provided one in his answer. Also note, that although not "built-in" to MATLAB, my answer links to how to access the Harwell-Boeing collection, most of which is sparse.

Answer (score 2):

`A = bucky()`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the **bucky** is indeed a function **.m file** instead of a **.mat** data file. I have found that there is no other sparse matrix **.mat** data file in matlab built-in software. see the below from a professor's  answer. @Mark L. Stone

Answer (score 0):

Below is from a Professor's answer.

> No.
>   It is straightforward to check this. west0479 resides in the demos folder where all such samples are kept.

```matlab
>> which west0479.mat
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\demos\west0479.mat
```

We can get a list of the .mat files in this folder which might contain sparse matrices.

```matlab
>> files = dir(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','demos','*.mat'))

files = 

  41×1 struct array with fields:

    name
    folder
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

Each of these files can be loaded and checked for sparse variables. Let's make an array from these checks and use it to index the list of files, so only files containing sparse matrices are returned:

```matlab
>> files(arrayfun(@(f) any(structfun(@issparse,load(fullfile(f.folder,f.name)))),files))

ans = 

  struct with fields:

       name: 'west0479.mat'
     folder: 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\demos'
       date: '14-Mar-2004 15:32:24'
      bytes: 12580
      isdir: 0
    datenum: 7.3202e+05
```

**west0479.mat** is the only one.